# Como simbolizar flechas en (Python)

Tags: python

-Se que el titulo puede ser un poco confuso, por ende, para poder establecer mi duda, dejo este codigo ...

windows ...

```
import msvcrt
while True:
    print(msvcrt.getch())
```

Linux

```
import getch
while True:
    print(getch.getch())
```

-Si no tiene el modulo, no importa, basicamente lo que hace el codigo es ir imprimiendo por pantalla lo que introduce el usuario (sin la necesidad de este de pulsar enter). Cuando descubri esto se me abrio un mar de posibilidades (aun sigo siendo algo novato), pero hasta la fecha, no he logrado ser capaz de saber si el usuario pulsa alguna flecha, partiendo de esta premisa, la pregunta seria : como simbolizar las flechas para poder hacer algo como esto ...

```
while True: 
    entrada = getch.getch()
    if entrada == flecha_derecha:
        print('Presionaste la flecha derecha')
    elif entrada == flecha_izquierda:
        print('Presionaste la flecha izquierda')
   ...
```

-Se que esto se prodria emular si simplemente interpretara a otras teclas como las flechas (de hecho, hice un modulo bastante simple para imprimir menus 'interactivos', si lo quiere ver :https://github.com/PySanti/modulos-de-python, agradeceria mucho una opinion de que podria mejorar ), sin embargo, no me parece tan comodo, y la duda me esta carcomiendo el alma

Comment: ¿que imprime tu codigo de ejemplo cuando pulsas la flecha? Prueba a imprimirlo con `print(repr(getch.getch()))`

Comment: No es tan simple como eso @abulafia. Ese comando devuelve una cadena byte que es igual para todas las flechas... Es decir, devuelve b'\xe0', al menos en windows 10.

Comment: Lo que varía aparece cuando volvés a ejecutar el comando, que devuelve algo que depende de que flecha sea.

Comment: @DanteS. exactamente, cuando se imprime con __str__ simplemente hace un salto de linea, en caso de imprimirlo con __repr__ hace lo que dice dante

Comment: Ya, por eso preguntaba. Pero en base a eso puedes hacer tu funcion `lee_tecla()`, que use getch() y si recibe el escape, lea otra vez y si no no, y retorne un codigo especial que puedes definir tu mismo para cada tecla, incluyendo las flechas.

Comment: Yo justo estaba creando algo así! Lo pongo de respuesta en cuanto lo termine @abulafia?

Comment: Este comando estoy usando para saber si faltan datos que recoger: https://docs.python.org/3/library/msvcrt.html#msvcrt.kbhit

Comment: @DanteS. de acuerdo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En esta respuesta no solo me enfoco en el asunto de las flechas, si no en todas las teclas posibles. NO tuve en cuenta combinaciones de teclas como `shift+c`. Recuerda que yo estoy en Windows y tengo teclado qwerty.

Hice una función que sirve para obtener tanto las flechas como las teclas FX y otras teclas especiales. A continuación mostraré la función con sus partes explicadas y una tabla con cada resultado que salió en mi compu.

#### Windows

```
import msvcrt

def get_key():
    # Espero a que el usuario presione una tecla.
    wait_key = msvcrt.getch()

    try:
        # Acá uso un diccionario de diccionarios para trabajar todas las combinaciones de teclas. Por ejemplo teclas[b'\xe0'][b'H'] será la flecha hacia arriba.
        teclas = {b'\xe0':{b'H':'up', b'P':'down', b'K':'left', b'M':'right', b'S':'supr', b'G':'inicio', b'I':'re pag', b'Q':'av pag', b'O':'fin', b'\x85':'F11', b'\x86':'F12'},
                  b'\x00':{b';':'F1', b'<':'F2', b'=':'F3', b'>':'F4', b'?':'F5', b'@':'F6', b'A':'F7', b'B':'F8', b'C':'F9', b'D':'F10'},
                  b'\xef':{b'+':'+'}}

        combos = [wait_key]
        resultado = teclas

        # Creo una lista que contendrá todo lo que se obtiene del comando getch hasta que la tecla termine de ser leida.
        while msvcrt.kbhit():
            combos.append(msvcrt.getch())

        # Proceso el diccionario de diccionarios para obtener la cadena que representa la tecla que se está presionando
        for item in combos:
            resultado = resultado[item]

        return resultado

    except KeyError:
        ### Si la tecla no es encontrada... ###

        if(len(combos) == 1):
            # Si hay un solo item en la lista combos, devuelvo ese unico item
            return combos[0]
        else:
            # De lo contrario, devuelvo la lista entera.
            return combos
```

#### Linux (no está probado)

```
import getch

def get_key():
    # Espero a que el usuario presione una tecla.
    wait_key = getch.getch()

    try:
        # Acá uso un diccionario de diccionarios para trabajar todas las combinaciones de teclas. Por ejemplo teclas[b'\xe0'][b'H'] será la flecha hacia arriba.
        teclas = {b'\xe0':{b'H':'up', b'P':'down', b'K':'left', b'M':'right', b'S':'supr', b'G':'inicio', b'I':'re pag', b'Q':'av pag', b'O':'fin', b'\x85':'F11', b'\x86':'F12'},
                  b'\x00':{b';':'F1', b'<':'F2', b'=':'F3', b'>':'F4', b'?':'F5', b'@':'F6', b'A':'F7', b'B':'F8', b'C':'F9', b'D':'F10'},
                  b'\xef':{b'+':'+'}}

        combos = [wait_key]
        resultado = teclas

        # Creo una lista que contendrá todo lo que se obtiene del comando getch hasta que la tecla termine de ser leida.
        while getch.kbhit():
            combos.append(getch.getch())

        # Proceso el diccionario de diccionarios para obtener la cadena que representa la tecla que se está presionando
        for item in combos:
            resultado = resultado[item]

        return resultado

    except KeyError:
        ### Si la tecla no es encontrada... ###

        if(len(combos) == 1):
            # Si hay un solo item en la lista combos, devuelvo ese unico item
            return combos[0]
        else:
            # De lo contrario, devuelvo la lista entera.
            return combos
```

Si no entiendes el diccionario de diccionarios, puedes observar que cosa devuelve cada tecla usando el siguiente programita junto a mi función:

```
while True:
    print(repr(get_key()))
```

En el caso de las flechas, la función devuelve

- 'up' para la flecha arriba
- 'down' para la flecha abajo
- 'left' para la flecha izquierda
- 'right' para la flecha derecha